# Swift 3: Replacing a "," with a "." in Double

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I‘m making my first own calculate app in Swift 3.
Everything is working fine expect decimal numbers.
Here in Germany is on the Decimal Pad a "," instead of a "."
Unfortunately you can‘t calculate with a "," in Swift.
Do you have any tips for me how to replace a "," with a "." in my project ?
Thanks tobi

```
let a = Double(WertA.text!)
let b = Double(WertB.text!)

let result = a! + b!
Ergebnis.text = String("/result")
```

Comment: Use (NS)NumberFormatter for both string -> double and double -> string conversions.

Comment: Thank you for your fast help @MartinR it worked :)